# How to fix set SSL role for the transport exception?

Tags: go, webrtc

I'm encountering a problem with Pion WebRTC. During step 6, when I try to call setRemoteDescription, I receive the following error:

> Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to apply the description for m= section with mid='0': Failed to set SSL role for the transport.

I believe that in step 6, the Pion server should return the answer SDP with a "setup passive" configuration, but I'm getting "active" instead.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: did you found any solution for it? if yes can you please share? im facing the same error